# How to sum a column with multiple conditions in R (fast version)

Tags: r

I have an issue with R, trying to code something for very large tables.

I'm trying to do, for each line in **test_cds** and for corresponding positions, the sum of the coverage *$cov* in **test_cov** table.

For example,
for **test_cds** line 1 :

```
         seqid source type start end
1 NW_019942502 Gnomon  CDS     1   3
```

positions between 1 and 3 include,
use :

```
> test_cov

        seqid  pos cov
1 NW_019942502   1  13
2 NW_019942502   2  16
3 NW_019942502   3  20
```

and do : sum(cov) for pos 1,2,3 = 13+16+20
in order to output :

```
> test_cds

         seqid source type start end sum_coverage
1 NW_019942502 Gnomon  CDS     1   3           49
```

**Warning : *$pos* range from 1 to +++ for each *$seqid*.**

Here's my input tables :

```
> test_cov

        seqid  pos cov
1 NW_019942502   1  13
2 NW_019942502   2  16
3 NW_019942502   3  20
(...)
4 NW_019942502  13  16
5 NW_019942502  14  16
6 NW_019942502  15  18

> test_cds

         seqid source type start end
1 NW_019942502 Gnomon  CDS     1   3   
2 NW_019942502 Gnomon  CDS    13  15   
3 NW_019942502 Gnomon  CDS    17  27  
4 NW_019942503 Gnomon  CDS     1  12   
5 NW_019942503 Gnomon  CDS    67  87
```

And expected output :

```
> test_cds

         seqid source type start end sum_coverage
1 NW_019942502 Gnomon  CDS     1   3           49
2 NW_019942502 Gnomon  CDS    13  15           50
```

To do so, I'm trying to use something like dplyr to replace a for() loop that will be way too long :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test_map)) {
  if (test_cov$seqid == test_cds$seqid & test_cov$pos >= test_cds$start & test_cov$pos <= test_cds$end) {
    test_cds$coverage <- sum(test_cov$cov)
  }
}
```

Many thanks !

Chloé

Comment: You can try non-equi-join in data.table. This answer I think does what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64202974/sum-partial-datatable-as-column-for-another-datatable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  We `seq` between `start` and `end` then use `separate_rows` to make the dataframe longer and create a `pos` column that we can join to `test_cov`.  Once we're joined it's trivial to `group_by` and `summarise`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

newtest_cds <- 
   test_cds %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(pos = paste(seq(start, 
                          end), 
                      collapse = ",")) %>%
   tidyr::separate_rows(pos) %>%
   mutate(pos = as.integer(pos))

newtest_cds
#> # A tibble: 50 x 6
#>    seqid        source type  start   end   pos
#>    <chr>        <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS       1     3     1
#>  2 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS       1     3     2
#>  3 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS       1     3     3
#>  4 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS      13    15    13
#>  5 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS      13    15    14
#>  6 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS      13    15    15
#>  7 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS      17    27    17
#>  8 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS      17    27    18
#>  9 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS      17    27    19
#> 10 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS      17    27    20
#> # … with 40 more rows

cds_cov <- right_join(newtest_cds, test_cov)
#> Joining, by = c("seqid", "pos")

cds_cov %>% 
   group_by(seqid, source, type, start, end) %>%
   summarise(sum_coverage = sum(cov))


#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#> # Groups:   seqid, source, type, start [2]
#>   seqid        source type  start   end sum_coverage
#>   <chr>        <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS       1     3           49
#> 2 NW_019942502 Gnomon CDS      13    15           50
```

Your sample data

```r
test_cds <- readr::read_table2("seqid source type start end
NW_019942502 Gnomon  CDS     1   3
NW_019942502 Gnomon  CDS    13  15
NW_019942502 Gnomon  CDS    17  27
NW_019942503 Gnomon  CDS     1  12
NW_019942503 Gnomon  CDS    67  87")

test_cov <- readr::read_table2("seqid  pos cov
NW_019942502   1  13
NW_019942502   2  16
NW_019942502   3  20
NW_019942502  13  16
NW_019942502  14  16
NW_019942502  15  18")
```

Comment: You're welcome please consider marking the checkbox if it resolved your question.